# Deleted fields keep being created after server restart

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a Grails application (Grails 2.4.4) where I use MySQL as database.
When I restart the server (in production) it keeps creating 2 columns in two diferent tables. The columns doenst exist anymore in domain classes.
This doesnt happen when im in development mode or when i deploy a war file in tomcat server (Tomcat 8), only if I reboot the server machine.

My DataSource.groovy look like this:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the code on Prod still has those two fields in the domain, so restarting it resync's.  And oh my gosh, relying on dbCreate="update" on prod is pretty fraught with peril.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's inconsistent, but `dbCreate = "update"` will configure Hibernate to attempt to sync up the database with the domain classes. Your best bet is to change that to `dbCreate = "none"` and use database migrations so you have full control over what's changed in the database structure.